# Taking the first observation from the group on a condition

Tags: sas

Suppose **i have** a table:

```
    id  date        N

    1   04FEB2017   1
    1   04FEB2017   .
    1   04FEB2017   2
    1   04FEB2017   .
    1   05FEB2017   3
    2   04FEB2017   4
    2   04FEB2017   5
```

It is sorted by id's, then by dates.

For all same `id`'s, for all same `date`'s, if `N` is not `null`, **i want to** keep only first row. So the result is:

```
 id  date        N

1   04FEB2017   1
1   04FEB2017   .
1   04FEB2017   .
1   05FEB2017   3
2   04FEB2017   4
```

**I tried** to rank, but that didnt push me to any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the data set is sorted, you can use the `BY` statement and the `FIRST.` syntax to find the first record in each group.

```
data have;
informat id 4. date date9. n 4.;
format date date9.;
input id date n;
datalines;
1 04FEB2017 1 
1 04FEB2017 . 
1 04FEB2017 2 
1 04FEB2017 . 
1 05FEB2017 3 
2 04FEB2017 4 
2 04FEB2017 5 
;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id date;

if first.date or missing(n) ;
run;
```

The second data step only keeps the first date or if n is missing.  This is edited based on the comment.

Comment: I misunderstood what you wanted.  Edit coming.